# Get math to show up in PDF bookmarks

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

Many math symbols get messed up in the PDF bookmarks.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{bookmark}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Is in $\in$, Set minus $\backslash$, Positive integers $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$}

Hello.
\end{document}
```

Output PDF:

[image]

$\in$ becomes a blank space, $\backslash$ becomes "026E30F, and $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ becomes Z+.

What I can do in Adobe Acrobat is to manually change the PDF bookmark, where I put in unicode math characters instead, like so:

> Is in ∈, Set minus \, Positive integers ℤ⁺

[image]

But I was wondering if I could do this in the tex file itself. I know for example that there is the possibility of entering an alternative "short title" for the title of a section/subsection/etc., so that this "short title" (instead of the actual title) shows up in the table of contents.

Is there a similar possibility for the PDF bookmark?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The math engine and different fonts are not possible in bookmarks. They are plain simple strings, but at least, they can be given in Unicode. The latter can be enabled by option `unicode` (or `pdfencoding=auto`) in `hyperref` that is used by package `bookmark` for converting the bookmark strings.

Option `psdextra` adds support for many symbols, especially math symbols.

`\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` can be used to redefine commands for bookmarks.
The example uses it to add support for `\backslash` by replacing it by the supported `\textbackslash`.

`\texorpdfstring` can be used to specify a bookmark replacement string:

- `\mathbb{Z}` is replaced by U+2124 (DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL Z) and
- the superscript `+` is replaced by U+207A (SUPERSCRIPT PLUS SIGN).

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[unicode,psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\backslash\textbackslash}

\begin{document}

\section{%
  Is in $\in$,
  Set minus $\backslash$,
  Positive integers \texorpdfstring{$\mathbb{Z}^{+}$}{\unichar{"2124}\unichar{"207A}}%
}

Hello.
\end{document}
```

The dollar signs for switching to and from math are automatically filtered out. If the warnings are of concern, then `\texorpdfstring` helps, e.g. `\texorpdfstring{$\in$}{\in}`.

Result (Adobe Reader):

> [image: Bookmark in Adobe Reader]

Comment: Is there any way to show the fractions with a **horizontal** fractional line in the **bookmark**? I do not mean the **diagonal/oblique** fractional line!  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427032/correct-math-representation-in-the-bookmark

Comment: @Famke Bookmarks are simple text strings, not suited for complicate math formulas.

Comment: My Dear Heiko Oberdiek, I can't use the `Unicode` for `mathcal{C}-(\unichar{"1D49E})` or the `Unicode` for `mathcal{C}-(\unichar{"1D4D2})`, so I replaced the `Unicode` for `mathfrak{C}-(\unichar{"212D})`, what was the problem with the `Unicodes` of length 5?

Comment: @Famke Just tested `\unichar{"1D49E}`. Works with `pdflatex` and AR. But the set of displayed characters depends on the PDF viewer. Restrict to simple characters for greater compatibility of PDF viewers. Anyway, math should be avoided in section titles in general for better style.