# Fraction in bookmarks

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

I have problem in bookmark. For example

```
\section{fraction $\frac{a}{b}$}
```

in bookmark is not true! Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short, **compilable** code resulting in your issue and add the **complete** error message to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Bookmarks are simple text strings. Macro `\texorpdfstring` can be used to specify the outcome on a PDF page and the string for the bookmarks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
  \section{Fraction \texorpdfstring{$\frac{a}{b}$}{a/b}}
\end{document}
```

There are lots of duplicates that provide more details, e.g.:

- [Get math to show up in PDF bookmarks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/417676/16967)
- [Math symbol in section heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251491/16967)